# Symfony: Controller\AdvertController::viewSlugAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$format" argument

Tags: symfony, routes

I am following the Symfony openclassrooms tutorial. I am currently at the chapter "routes avancées". I also posted my question there.

I am trying to open this local URL:
http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/platform/2011/webmaster
or
the same url with the html extension

But I keep getting this error message:

[image: error1]

My resources/config/routing.yml is as follows:
I am not sure about the path in neo_platform_home. I tried both, with and without the slash.

```
neo_platform_home:
    path:    /
    defaults: {_controller: NeoPlatformBundle:Advert:index}

neo_platform_view:
    path:   /advert/{id}
    defaults: {_controller: NeoPlatformBundle:Advert:view}

neo_platform_view_slug:

    path:    /{year}/{slug}.{_format}

    defaults:

        _controller: NeoPlatformBundle:Advert:viewSlug
        _format: html
    requirements:
        year:    \d{4}
        format: html|xml


neo_platform_add:
    path:   /add
    defaults: {_controller: NeoPlatformBundle:Adert:add}
```

The /app/config/routing.yml is as folows:

```
neo_platform:
    resource: "@NeoPlatformBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"

    prefix:   /platform
```

When I try to open the url with the .xml extension, I get this error message:
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

> at vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Controller/ArgumentResolver.php:78
>    ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

difficult to answer without your code, but it look like your forgrgot to pass the `$format` to your viewSlugAction controller

Comment: Your comment made me realise that I had to chage every where $format to $_format. I had done it only in the routing.yml but had not thought of doing it in AdvertController.php. That solved the problem. Thank you so much!